# Get the distance between two Addresses in google sheets with mode transit

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, maps, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the distance between A an B with the mode transit.

This is my code on google sheets(excel)

```
=importXML("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="& A4  & "&destinations=" & D4 & "&mode=transit&arrival_time=1391374800&key=MYKEYHERE"; "//distance/text")
```

It says the the "Url can not be called".
Im sitting on this problem for some time and i would appreciate any help.

Other then importing XML and in the code it says `/json?origin` I don't really understand the problem.

EDIT: I found this in the Doc

```
<travel_mode>TRANSIT</travel_mode>
    <start_location>
     <lat>40.7563670</lat>
     <lng>-73.9907530</lng>
    </start_location>
    <end_location>
     <lat>40.8179080</lat>
     <lng>-74.0656630</lng>
```

But im not sure how to input it in the line above.
I do the all the long and lat for the destination and origin.

Comment: And have you tried outputting the final url and trying it manually? Is it valid? According to the docs, ImportXML can accept many forms of xml feed, it doesn't state it can accept json (if that's actually being returned). My first port of call would be to test the final url, make sure it's valid, and returns what you expect it to.

Comment: Hey im not really sure what you mean, im a newbie at this. Also can you check the edit above ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the answer

```
 =importXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?&origins="& A4 & "&destinations=" & D4 & "&mode=transit&key=YOURKEYHERE"; "//distance/text")
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can build a custom function to use on your sheet,
on your sheet's menu go for: Tools > Script editor and paste this:

```
/**
* @customFunction
*/
function getDistanceBetween(originLat, originLong, destLat, destLong) {
    var directions, route;

    // Create a new Direction finder using Maps API available on Google Apps Script
    directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(originLat, originLong)
    .setDestination(destLat, destLong)
    .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
    .getDirections(); // Direction Object

    // The path may have some segments so it sum it all
    if(directions.routes[0]){
        route = directions.routes[0].legs.reduce(function(acc, currentRow){
            acc.dist += currentRow.distance.value/1000;
            acc.dur += currentRow.duration.value/60;
            return acc;
        },{dist:0,dur:0});

        // This will return data to fill 2 columns. 
        // First with de distance
        // Second with a link to view the path on map's site;
        return [[route.dist, "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+originLat+","+originLong+"/"+destLat+","+destLong+"/"]];
    } else {
        return [["", ""]];
    }
}
```

Then go on your sheet and set this to a cell:

`=getDistanceBetween(-23.319937, -51.166299, -23.310565, -51.165488)`
// Or a cell reference;

Answer (score -2):

I was also looking for a way to do this, having never used a custom google function on sheets before, and found: this gist https://gist.github.com/simonwhatley/4ea2e87815747bf14d1d247181248512

It's pretty much ready to go out of the box and the only complicated part is adding it to sheets.

To use it:

1. Open a sheet file then go to `Tools` > `Script Editor`
2. Fill in whatever you want for the project name
3. Copy the gist to `code.gs`
4. Click save
5. In google sheets call `=GOOGLEDISTANCE()` whenever you want to use the function

For example:

```
=GOOGLEDISTANCE(A1, A2, "diriving", "minutes")
=GOOGLEDISTANCE("100 Someplace", "200 otherplace", "driving", "minutes")
=GOOGLEDISTANCE("22.5985, 47.6767", "45.3545, 23.44545", "walking", "minutes")
```

Be sure to customise the locale in the gist to your actual location. E.g `UK` > `US`

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Tools > Script editor no longer exists its it now under add on

Answer (score -2):

That function GOOGLEDISTANCE() works well! I've stepped up my Sheets skill set.